# How should I resolve bug Uncaught SyntaxError with '<' in React.js app<'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am getting 2 errors as below in my React.js application. After analyzing in the console, the errors refer to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. How can this issue be resolved? I am only interested in these 2 errors because the rest has been fixed! Link to the application [Delightartco](https://vigorous-tesla-ec685c.netlify.app/). I would also ask for a brief feedback on the application. I mean the design and correct code semantics.

[image: BUGS]

Comment: Can you share the code?  Seems like a syntactical error.

Comment: @Sid Link to the repository https://github.com/radgoll/delightartco